# Rails tool to search for untranslated strings using yaml locale files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

Is there a way to look up all keys used in the rails application and add the untranslated keys to the different yaml locale files?

The tool should scan all the helpers, controllers, views, ... to look for keys being used. Next it should check whether the key is already added to the different locale yaml files.

I'm using the I18n that ships default with Rails.

Update: I'm kind of searching for a rake task that will just search my app for translations keys followed by a look up in the yaml locale files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For finding "untranslated" entries, I believe that any sufficiently advanced **diff** tool will do (you actually want to just filter the similarities, hiding differences.)
However, please keep in mind that this way you will only find the strings that are exactly the same as English. In other words it doesn't mean that they will be untranslated - some of them might sound exactly the same as English in a target language.

To actually make sure that something is or is not translated, I would recommend using [Translation Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_memory). That will put you in control. However, for small projects it might be an overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like i18n-tasks?
https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks

> This gem analyses code statically for key usages, such as
>   I18n.t('some.key'), in order to:
>
> - Report keys that are missing or unused.
> - Pre-fill missing keys, optionally from Google Translate or DeepL Pro.
> - Remove unused keys.